# Code won't execute after getOutputStream - Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get some data from a webservice with POST command. But I am stuck with this weird thing: my code doesn't get execute after a certain point and I really don't know why. I used breakpoints and Log.d() to check it.

```
private void getResponse(String code)
    {
        String strurl = "http://example.com/api/something.json";
        String Token = app.Settings.UserToken;
        String myid= app.ID.toString();



        try {
            URL url = new URL(strurl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000); 
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

            String outstr = "{\"response\": {";
            outstr += "\"token\":\"" + Token + "\",";
            outstr += "\"myid\":\"" + myid+ "\",";
            outstr += "\"code\":\"" + code + "\",";
            outstr += "}}";

            out.write(outstr.getBytes());

            int respCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (respCode == 200) {

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, new BooleanTypeAdapter())
                        .create();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));


                reader.beginObject();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String token = reader.nextName();

                    if (token.equals("name")) {

                    }

                }
                reader.endObject();

                reader.close();
            } else {
                return;
            }
            urlConnection.disconnect();


            return;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally {

        }
    }
```

After this line

```
OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
```

nothing gets executed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was. I was getting a networkonmainthreadexception because I didn't run the function inside an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Simple flush after writing for sending message to file-descriptor.

```
out.flush();
```